# Необходимо получить небольшой текстовый файл с сайта, подредактировать его и отправить обратно

Tags: javascript, php

Пробовал

1:

```
<script >
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'file.php', false);               
  xhr.send();
</script>
```

2:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($file); $i++) {
  echo '<div contentEditable="true">';
  echo htmlspecialchars($file[$i]);
  echo '</div>';
} //for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($file); $i++) {
```

Файл редактируется, но как его в отредактированном виде передать в php скрипт.
Я начинающий, прошу строго не судить

Comment: Вместо div'а с contenteditable используйте `<textarea></textarea>`. А "передать" Это надо делать POST запрос с этими данными

Comment: Огромное спасибо, получилось как и требовалось. Как мне это не пришло в голову?

Comment: @InDevX а почему не надо contenteditable использовать? Так же взял innerHTML и всё

Comment: @АлексейШиманский потому что div'ы не для этого предназначены и _Я начинающий_.. Фича старая, но применяется до сих пор в единицах сайтов - это о чём-то да говорит. Я вижу только одно применение им - в какой-то читалке для исправления ошибок в тексте

Comment: А что предпочтительней: innerHTML или <textarea></textarea>? Во втором варианте мне нравится, что обходимся без JavaScript (который я, к сожалению, пока не знаю).